# How to get my SELECT query to combine and return data from two different tables

Tags: android, database, sqlite, select

I have two tables one of them is called OrderEntry having fields SKU, QTY and DATE, the second table is called DefineRawMat and has fields RAWMAT, SKU and PORTION. I am trying to combine both tables and after that save the data into a new table. It is only the SKU field that is common to both tables, but is not Unique as their could be the same SKU value appearing multiple times in each table. I have a SELECT query which runs without error but returns the message to me 0 rows returned in 0ms from:

I have been at it for a while and cannot understand what the issue may be. The SKU data in both fields are identical as it is feed via a spinner from a master data, so it cannot be data issues.

here is my query

```
SELECT OE_Sales_Activity.FP_SKU, Quantity, RawMaterialPortion, Define_Raw_Material_Portioning.FP_SKU
FROM OE_Sales_Activity
inner JOIN Define_Raw_Material_Portioning on Define_Raw_Material_Portioning.FP_SKU = OE_Sales_Activity.FP_SKU;
```

Comment: Do you have access to the database? FIre select query on both tables separately. And manually check is there any `SKU` is common

Comment: Try `trim(Define_Raw_Material_Portioning on Define_Raw_Material_Portioning.FP_SKU) = trim(OE_Sales_Activity.FP_SKU)` just in case.

Comment: @ Ashish, yes I do.. when I include an _id and use this as the common key i am able to pull data but thats not correct because the OE data base is transnational and therefore the data dynamic

Comment: @Forpas.. it worked. apparantly there was some space at the beginning of each data item in one of the tables. I normally use the data.getText().toString().toTrim function in my code, I must have let it out in this case. Many thanks